# How can i fork litecoin 0.15 to create my own coin

Tags: c++, bitcoin, litecoin

I tried following step in

https://www.hackster.io/pjdecarlo/how-to-make-a-cryptocurrency-using-litecoin-v0-15-source-fb5e82

but i cannot create my own currency. I am facing issue creating genesis and updating the source code.
Is there any guide or something i can follow

the error i faced:

```
chainparams.cpp:126: CMainParams::CMainParams(): Assertion `consensus.hashGenesisBlock == uint256S("0x649027171c04bf7efd160c3d26e84cc4d6d3b500c6fcfab5e77cbfff788014aa")' failed.
```

i added

```
printf("%s\ngenesis\n", consensus.hashGenesisBlock.ToString().c_str());
printf("%s\nmerkle\n", genesis.hashMerkleRoot.ToString().c_str());
```

to chainparams.cpp, now i am facing

```
ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at CBlockDiskPos(nFile=0, nPos=8)
```

Comment: that's because the source code is in c++

Comment: is there any solution to the above problem?